# How to add dynamically HTML with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to add HTML code after clicking a button.

Here is the thing; you input the tab's name then click the button linked to the addTab function. Then I tried to write the code using createElement(), setAttribute() and appendChild() but nothing works.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function addTab() {
  var tabname = entree.value;
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = tabname;
  btn.setAttribute("class", "tablinks")
  btn.setAttribute("onlick", "openTab(event, ${tabname})");
  var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  document.tabbar.appendChild(btn);

  var tabdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  document.body.appendChild(tabdiv);
  tabdiv.setAttribute("id", tabname);
  tabdiv.setAttribute("class", "tabcontent")

  var tabp = document.createElement("P");
  var tabptxt = document.createTextNode("Réussite.");
  tabp.appendChild(tabptxt);
}
```

```css
header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <label>Enter tab's name : </label>
  <input type="text" id="entree" minlength="4" maxlength="12" size="12">
  <button onclick="addTab()">VALIDER</button>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, '12septembre')">12septembre</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, '7octobre')">7octobre</button>
  </div>
  <div id="12septembre" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>12 septembre</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="7octobre" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>7 octobre</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

As I'm not experimented using `Js`, i get lost easily!
I also wondered, is this the best way to add tabs dynamically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `btn.setAttribute("onlick", "openTab(event, ${tabname})");` <-- wrong, because the sting will be unquouted and you really should be using addEventListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## the problem

You were almost there, there are 2 problems in your js making it to fail :

```
var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
document.tabbar.appendChild(btn);
```

- you called the variable `tabbar` but on next line try to call it with the name `document.tabbar` which is not the same thing, this can be seen in the browser console: it's telling `document.tabbar is undefined`.
- you misused [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), you probably thought it return an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) but in fact it returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), a sort of array with less buitin method, so you need to get your element out of the collection.

here's a corrected version of these 2 lines :

```
var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0];
tabbar.appendChild(btn);
```

---

## use `id`s instead of `class` in js

I personnaly prefer using `id`s to get element with [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), since `id` **MUST** be unique so a good formed HTML will always have only one element with this `id`

also `document.getElementById` returns an `HTMLElement` so no need to look for the wanted Element in an a Collection

and finally since using `class` as a vulnerability, if you ever add another `tag` with the same class before the current one then your `tabbar` will become the second element of the `HTMLCollection`

---

## another error you didn't see yet

as mentionned by [epascarello in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693027/how-to-add-dynamically-html-with-js/57693406?noredirect=1#comment101830936_57693027)

```
btn.setAttribute("onlick", "openTab(event, ${tabname})");
```

should be written

```
btn.setAttribute("onlick", `openTab(event, '${tabname}')`);
```

with `` ` `` instead of `"` to use the expension of [`template litterals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

as a note : it is considered bad practise to define event in the HTML, you should do it like this :

```
btn.addEventListener('click', openTab)
```

or you can also use

```
btn.onlick = function() { openTab(btn, tabname); } // or
btn.onlick = () => openTab(btn, tabname);
```

but these two ways to write it requires you to modify `openTab`
replacing

```
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

by

```
btn.className += " active"
```

---

## a corrected version

and finally a corrected version of your snippets (I didn't touch anything except these 3 lines)

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function addTab() {
    var tabname = entree.value;
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = tabname;
    btn.setAttribute("class", "tablinks")
    btn.setAttribute("onlick", `openTab(event, '${tabname}')`);
    var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0];
    tabbar.appendChild(btn);

    var tabdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    document.body.appendChild(tabdiv);
    tabdiv.setAttribute("id", tabname);
    tabdiv.setAttribute("class", "tabcontent")

    var tabp = document.createElement("P");
    var tabptxt = document.createTextNode("Réussite.");
    tabp.appendChild(tabptxt);
}
```

```css
header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <label>Enter tab's name : </label>
    <input type="text" id="entree" minlength="4" maxlength="12" size="12">
    <button onclick="addTab()">VALIDER</button>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, '12septembre')">12septembre</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, '7octobre')">7octobre</button>
    </div>
    <div id="12septembre" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>12 septembre</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="7octobre" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>7 octobre</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

there are also some other things to say on your code but it's mainly because you don't know JS native API enought yet.

Comment: Still has another issue which I mentioned in a comment

Comment: @epascarello didn't see that one

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot for your help, I can understand my mistakes and that essential to me. Have a good day! Oh tes @epascarello indeed I need to use addEventListener, thanks a lot!

Comment: @rems added a part about the error mentionned by epascarello

Comment: @jonatjano yes that's perfect, thanks ;) but the code doesn't save the modifications ? As I'd like to put this code on my wordpress website, i got to keep the added tabs on!

Comment: @Rems you mean like keeping the tab after reloading the page ? In that case you'll need to send back informations to the server, to save the state somewhere, and get it back when you reload the page. That's many things to do and really goes outside the scope of this question. You should look for `JS Fetch API` for the communication with the server, and to store the state between session, maybe PHP can write files, but the best would be to use some database. You'll need to learn some more things :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Like above you can add a debugger in browser console and check

```
var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
```

in here `tabbar` will return `HTMLCollection` so we have to get only the element from the Collection. we can get the element from the collection like below.

```
var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
tabbar[0].appendChild(btn);
```

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function addTab() {
    var tabname = entree.value;
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = tabname;
    btn.setAttribute("class", "tablinks")
    btn.setAttribute("onlick", "openTab(event, ${tabname})");
    var tabbar = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    tabbar[0].appendChild(btn);

    var tabdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    document.body.appendChild(tabdiv);
    tabdiv.setAttribute("id", tabname);
    tabdiv.setAttribute("class", "tabcontent")

    var tabp = document.createElement("P");
    var tabptxt = document.createTextNode("Réussite.");
    tabp.appendChild(tabptxt);
}
```

```css
header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <label>Enter tab's name : </label>
    <input type="text" id="entree" minlength="4" maxlength="12" size="12">
    <button onclick="addTab()">VALIDER</button>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, '12septembre')">12septembre</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, '7octobre')">7octobre</button>
    </div>
    <div id="12septembre" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>12 septembre</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="7octobre" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>7 octobre</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes! It's working too. Thanks a lot! Just need to change my button attribution of the onclick

Comment: @ShakirAhamed the answer is good but it can be better by explaining what you changed, and why it needed to be changed

Answer (score -1):

Try Jquery!
For example:

```
this.$OuterDiv = $('<div></div>')
.hide()
.append($('<table></table>')
    .attr({ id : tabname })
    .addClass("tabcontent")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this!